# Using models in React and React native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, model, redux

**Context**

Lately, during the development of a personal app there was a misunderstanding between the backend developer and myself. This misunderstanding led to a small change in the API for which the app was not prepared to handle (a field was removed from an object response data) and consequently led to crashes when the related component was mounted.

**Possible solution**

After that I realized that just by adding a model which could just provide the basic values that the app needs to work, just a basic class implementation of the request (let's say a book data i.e.), could have leveraged the impact of the issue.

**Actual question**

As I've seen few information about the topic I would like to ask the react / react native community if this approach is anti-pattern in some way or it is actually a valid solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `propTypes` or `defaultProps` to catch and handle this issue from the component level.

As far as in general having a client validate the response data from an API, I think the way you want to use it could be an anti-pattern in that a client should not be used to test/assert what that response data ought to be.

In your specific situation, perhaps a better solution is to ***maintain the test cases for the API***. This will let you officially communicate to your backend developer what your expectations are, and avoid these problems in the future.